# cosmosdb geospatial look up return blank

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using cosmosDB to do a $geowithin lookup and when i run the query in the cosmosdb data explorer it works fine and returns the right set.  When i run it in node js using the MongoClient I get back a empty set.

This is the query i ran in cosmosdb data explorer:

```
   {CurrentLoc: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $centerSphere: [[-122.0312186,37.33233141], 0.0025232135647961246]
            }
        }}
```

That returned the correct list of documents

This is in my node app:

```
var toFind = {
        CurrentLoc: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $centerSphere: [currentLoc, maxDistance]
            }
        }
    }


    var query = db.collection('User').find(toFind)
    query.toArray(function (err, doc, queryResult) {
      logger.debug ('result: ' + JSON.stringify(doc);
})
```

That returns a blank set and does not get the data back.  Why would it be returning different things and also why is it blank?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to break down the `currentLoc` variable into an array of two values, so the query is structured in the same manner as when executed through **CosmosDB Data Explorer**:

**[-122.0312186,37.33233141]** in
`$centerSphere: [[-122.0312186,37.33233141], 0.0025232135647961246]`

Hope it helps!